# MySQL query the same amount of states in a set amount of records returned

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a phone column and a state column. Can i query a specific LIMIT of lets say 500 but I want every state thats available in the state column to have an equal amount of each in the 500 count query.

ex: table = `ironman`

```
appid
phone(PK)
firstname
lastname
address
city
state
zip
called_count
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
FROM ironman
(A scripts that gives me (x amount) of phone numbers from each state)
WHERE called_count <= 4
LIMIT 500 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: Which MySQL version? use `SELECT VERSION()` .. I assume you want a `LIMIT` per state group? See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providng example data and expected results on a smaller scale then 10.000 records.

Comment: using version 8.0.15

Comment: redid the question a bit to better understand the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER() to assign the rows a position within a state group. Then order the rows by that postion. When you then apply a LIMIT, there will be the same number of rows from each state (+-1) - (assuming you have enough phone numbers for each state).

```
with numbered as (
  select i.*
       , row_number() over (partition by state order by phone) pos
  from ironman i
  -- put your WHERE clause here
), limited as (
  select *
  from numbered
  order by pos asc, state asc
  limit 6 -- set your limit here
)
select *
from limited
order by state, phone
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pxfWVPDqyUL1ZdefHWnBsE/0)

If you want the phone numbers to be selected randomly - change the ORDER for position

```
row_number() over (partition by state order by rand()) pos
```